# How to assign to a single element of dataset in Matlab statistics toolbox?

Tags: matlab, statistics

In an example below how to set Ann's age to 40?

```
>> d(1,1).Name='John'; d(1,1).Age=30;
>> d(2,1).Name='Anne'; d(2,1).Age=31;
>> ds=struct2dataset(d,'ReadObsNames','Name');
>> ds
ds = 
            Age
    John    30 
    Anne    31 
>> ds(2,'Name')
Error using getvarindices (line 25)
Unrecognized variable name 'Name'.
Error in dataset/subsrefParens (line 19)
varIndices = getvarindices(a, s(1).subs{2});
Error in dataset/subsref (line 69)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = subsrefParens(a,s); 
>> ds(2,'Age')
ans = 
            Age
    Anne    31 
>> ds(2,'Age')=40
Error using dataset/subsasgnParens (line 198)
Right hand side must be a dataset array.
Error in dataset/subsasgn (line 79)
    a = subsasgnParens(a,s,b,creating);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it: with braces:

```
>> ds{2,'Age'}=40
ds = 
            Age
    John    30 
    Anne    40
```